# Love2d console on PyCharm only writes to console after closing

Tags: lua, pycharm, jetbrains-ide, love2d

I'm using PyCharm community edition to create a love2d application. I've created a hotkey that runs a `.bat` file to run it with `lovec.exe` which is opens the console as the app runs, then i've created an `external tool` to run the `.bat`file through a keyboard shortcut, when i use it, the console opens within PyCharm, which doesn't write anything, and after closing the app, everything that was meant to have been written appears, when i run the `.bat` file outside of PyCharm it functions perfectly.

I would like to know if there's either an obvious fix to that or, just how to run the console outside of pycharm through an external tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is due to the way Lua delays writing files, known as "buffering." To change it, put the following command at the top of your file:

```lua
io.stdout:setvbuf( 'no' ) -- Switches buffering for stdout to be off
```

Read more in Lua's [manual](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-file:setvbuf):

> **`file:setvbuf (mode [, size])`**
>
> Sets the buffering mode for an output file. There are three available modes:
>
> - **"no"**: no buffering; the result of any output operation appears immediately.
> - **"full"**: full buffering; output operation is performed only when the buffer is full or when you explicitly `flush` the file (see `io.flush`).
> - **"line"**: line buffering; output is buffered until a newline is output or there is any input from some special files (such as a terminal device).
>
> For the last two cases, `size` specifies the size of the buffer, in bytes. The default is an appropriate size.